# Monitoring custom events in chrome?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out where an event is firing from, and I'm having zero luck.

So we have this:

```
this.model.on('change:inventory', this.inventory_callback, this);
```

And I set a breakpoint there and tried this in the chrome dev tools console:

```
monitorEvents(this.model)
```

But I got nothing. Tips? Advice? What am I doing wrong? Can I do it this way? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monitorEvents()` is intended for tracking native DOM events only. According to the tip-of-tree source ([source code link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js&q=file%3ainjectedscriptsource.js%20_normalizeEventTypes&sq=package%3achromium&l=1561)), this is the comprehensive list of monitor-able event types (read "event names prefixed by"):

- "mouse"
- "key"
- "touch"
- "control"
- "load"
- "unload"
- "abort"
- "error"
- "select"
- "change"
- "submit"
- "reset"
- "focus"
- "blur"
- "resize"
- "scroll"
- "search"
- "devicemotion"
- "deviceorientation"

Comment: ... _native DOM events only._